# nextjs react recoil persist values in local storage: initial page load in wrong state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, string-interpolation, recoiljs

I have the following code,

```ts
const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const darkMode = useRecoilValue(darkModeAtom)
    
    console.log('darkMode: ', darkMode)
    return (
        <div className={`max-w-6xl mx-auto my-2 ${darkMode ? 'dark' : ''}`}>
            <Nav />
            {children}
            <style jsx global>{`
                body {
                    background-color: ${darkMode ? '#12232e' : '#eefbfb'};
                }
            `}</style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am using recoil with [recoil-persist](https://github.com/polemius/recoil-persist).
So, when the darkMode value is true, the className should include a dark class, right? but it doesn't. I don't know what's wrong here. But it just doesn't work when I refresh for the first time, after that it works fine. I also tried with darkMode === true condition and it still doesn't work. You see the styled jsx, that works fine. That changes with the darkMode value and when I refresh it persists the data. But when I inspect I don't see the dark class in the first div. Also, when I console.log the darkMode value, I see true, but the dark class is not included.

Here's the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/live/gknsbr3)

Maybe it's a silly mistake, But I wasted a lot of time on this. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that during SSR (server side rendering) there is no `localStorage`/`Storage` object available. So the resulted html coming from the server always has `darkMode` set to `false`. That's why you can see in cosole mismatched markup errors on hydration step.

I'd assume using some state that will always be `false` on the initial render (during hydration step) to match SSR'ed html but later will use actual `darkMode` value. Something like:

```ts
// themeStates.ts
import * as React from "react";
import { atom, useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { recoilPersist } from "recoil-persist";

const { persistAtom } = recoilPersist();

export const darkModeAtom = atom<boolean>({
  key: "darkMode",
  default: false,
  effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtom]
});

export function useDarkMode() {
  const [isInitial, setIsInitial] = React.useState(true);
  const [darkModeStored, setDarkModeStored] = useRecoilState(darkModeAtom);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsInitial(false);
  }, []);

  return [
    isInitial === true ? false : darkModeStored,
    setDarkModeStored
  ] as const;
}
```

And inside components use it like that:

```ts
// Layout.tsx
  const [darkMode] = useDarkMode();
// Nav.tsx
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useDarkMode();
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-davinci-fqujo?file=/src/states/themeStates.ts)

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked. I just have a question though, do I always have to make a custom hook to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I believe most of the libraries working with SSR are accounting for that behavior from the start. I'm surprised the `recoil-persist` doesn't. Though maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Extending on @aleksxor solution, you can perform the `useEffect` once as follows.

First create an atom to handle the SSR completed state and a convenience function to set it.

```js
import { atom, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil"

const ssrCompletedState = atom({
  key: "SsrCompleted",
  default: false,
})

export const useSsrComplectedState = () => {
  const setSsrCompleted = useSetRecoilState(ssrCompletedState)
  return () => setSsrCompleted(true)
}
```

Then in your code add the hook. Make sure it's an inner component to the Recoil provider.

```
const setSsrCompleted = useSsrComplectedState()
useEffect(setSsrCompleted, [setSsrCompleted])
```

Now create an atom effect to replace the recoil-persist `persistAtom`.

```js
import { AtomEffect } from "recoil"
import { recoilPersist } from "recoil-persist"

const { persistAtom } = recoilPersist()

export const persistAtomEffect = <T>(param: Parameters<AtomEffect<T>>[0]) => {
  param.getPromise(ssrCompletedState).then(() => persistAtom(param))
}
```

Now use this new function in your atom.

```js
export const darkModeAtom = atom({
  key: "darkMode",
  default: false,
  effects_UNSTABLE: [persistAtomEffect]
})
```

Comment: Work's like charm THX!

Comment: There is a minor typo in the function, but works like a charm :), thank you very much
`export const persistAtomEffect = <T,>(param: Parameters<AtomEffect<T>>[0]) => {
  param.getPromise(ssrCompletedState).then(() => persistAtom(param));
};

`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

1. copy these code.
   https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects/#local-storage-persistence
2. replace localStorage with [nookies](https://github.com/maticzav/nookies).

```
import { parseCookies, setCookie, destroyCookie } from "nookies";

const cookies = parseCookies();
const localStorageEffect =
  (key) =>
  ({ setSelf, onSet }) => {
    const savedValue = cookies[key];
    if (savedValue != null) {
      setSelf(JSON.parse(savedValue));
    }

    onSet((newValue, _, isReset) => {
      isReset
        ? destroyCookie(null, key)
        : setCookie(null, key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
    });
  };
```

3. fixed Hydration issue.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/72318597/5451474

[my demo code](https://github.com/ZeviLiao/recoil-demo/blob/main/components/states.js)