# React 18: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get [SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) working in my app, but I get the error:

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was
> rendered on the server.

Live demo code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j94bwy).

Live demo of problem is [here](https://react-j94bwy.stackblitz.io/) (open dev tools console to see the errors):

#### File *App.js*

```
 import React from "react";

  class App extends React.Component {

  head() {
    return (
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <title>React App</title>
      </head>
    );
  }

  body() {
    return (
      <body>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Client says Hello World</h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.head()}
        {this.body()}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

#### File *index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { StrictMode } from "react";

import App from "./App";


//const container = document.getElementById("root");
const container = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
  container,
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

The HTML template shown in the live demo is served by the backend and generated using the following code:

```
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

const clientHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
<StrictMode>
    <App />
</StrictMode>
)

// Serve clientHtml to client
```

I need to dynamically generate `<head></head> and <body></body>` section as shown in the App class.

Comment: Can we all agree this error message is worse than useless?!

Comment: This error can be triggered by extensions such as Dashlane or LastPass since they inject html post-render messing up the comparison between server and client html structure, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75490907/5213598

Comment: The answerers of this question have a truly ***astounding*** ability to misspell [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)... It is Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js, Next.js.

Comment: In any case, why do we need more than 60 answers to this question?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same problem lately with Next.js and I am not sure if my observations are applicable to other libraries.

I had been wrapping my components with an improper tag that is, Next.js is not comfortable having a **p** tag wrapping your [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements)s, **sections**, etc., so it will yell "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server".

I solved this problem by examining how my elements were wrapping each other. With [material UI](https://material-ui.com/) you would need to be cautious. For example, if you use a typography component as a wrapper, the default value of the component prop is "p", so you will experience the error if you don't change the component value to something semantic.

In my own opinion, based on my personal experience, the problem is caused by improper arrangement of HTML elements and to solve the problem in the context of Next.js, one will have to reevaluate how they are arranging their HTML element.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
/**
 * This might give that error
 */
export const IncorrectComponent = ()=>{
  return(
    <p>
      <div>This is not correct and should never be done because the p tag has been abused</div>
      <Image src='/vercel.svg' alt='' width='30' height='30'/>
    </p>
  )
}

/**
 * This will work
 */
export const CorrectComponent = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <div>This is correct and should work because a div is really good for this task.</div>
      <Image src='/vercel.svg' alt='' width='30' height='30'/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This comment on React's Github sums up the issue nicely https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24519#issuecomment-1122780621.

Comment: In my case, I had a `Text` component which put its `children` inside an `Elem` which apparently was a `<p>` by default. Hydration failed when the `children` was dangerously set inner HTML . Got rid of the component, and it works fine now. (I could have changed the component config to use a different element. But I realized I didn't need the component there.)

Comment: Thank you! In my example, I used tr inside the table, when I wrap my tr tags with body it's solved. Wrong path  table>tr | Success path table > tbody > tr

Comment: The problem with my code was that I put an Image Tag inside a Link Tag.

Comment: In my case I had a Link wrapping a div and inside the div a button with href attribute was causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this I had the same problem caused by a `div` rendered into a `button`, turning the former into a `span` solved the issue

Comment: In my case, I had a button inside a button because of a third-party lib

Comment: In my case I had wrapped a div with Next.js ```<link>``` component

Comment: Wow, in my case it wasn't even MY code. I had a Chrome Extension for downloading images in 1 click, and it was introducing an invalid tag in all my images, so SSR failed.

Comment: Ese componente Typography me tiene hasta las pelotas siempre da problemas.

Comment: I had a missing `<tbody>` inside the `<table>`around some `<tr>`.

Comment: @Motsi I'm using framer-motion's motion wrapping my section for animation, that section does happen to have form. How do I work around this problem without having to change my requirement?

Comment: For the curious ones : This is a great read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: In my case, I have my <nav> component outside of <body> component, that causing the issue.

Comment: The error should say something like `improper HTML element arrangement` or `invalid HTML` instead of `the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server`.

Answer (score 76):

Importing and running some of the packages can cause this error too. For example, when I used Swiper.js package I encountered this problem. It's mostly because the package is using Window object somewhere.

Since it isn't a good practice to modify the content of the package itself, the best way to tackle such issues is to render the component only after the DOM is loaded. So you can try this.

```
const Index = () => {
  const [domLoaded, setDomLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDomLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {domLoaded && (
        <Swiper>
          <div>Test</div>
        </Swiper>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: but what if the slider taking half of the screen size and on top of the page? this will create a CLS issue which is far worse than the hydration one

Comment: Instead of conditional rendering, try to set the visibility:hidden based on domLoaded,
`return (
    <div style={domLoaded?undefined:{visibility: 'hidden'}}>
        <Swiper>
          <div>Test</div>
        </Swiper>
    <div/>
  );`

Comment: Holy crap! I cannot believe this was it!

Comment: @singularity why the visibitily should be better?

Comment: This works, but if you implement, you need to be cognizant of the performance issues this implementation could cause.

Answer (score 35):

If you're using a `table`, you probably missed `<tbody>`.

Incorrect:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Correct:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 21):

So let me explain why this error can occur in your Next.js application.

There are some tags that you can't use inside another tag.
For example, you can't use [`div`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) inside a [`td`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) tag. You can't use the [`p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag inside a [`span`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span). The same goes for other tags like [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), [`ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), etc.

**UPDATE**: The article on [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser) can help to understand why this error occur.

You need to go to your code and remove all the invalid tags used.
In my case, I used an [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag inside `span` which is invalid.

This is invalid

```html
<span>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://askhumans.io"> Login </a>
</span>
```

This is valid.

```html
  <a target="_blank" href="https://askhumans.io"> <span>  Login </span> </a>
```

Comment: Can you provide some documentation or other citation for this? It would also be helpful if this is indeed the case for there to be a linter or similar that can point out these issues.

Comment: Comes with trial and error, as not sure which tag isn't working in the beginning.

Comment: @maxcountryman i found no documentation but find out that this relate to how browser parse your html. If we tried to wrap div tag inside p tag, the div tag always render outside and right after the p tag, no framework or library required!

Comment: @sonphung.xf I have added the link in the answer for more details.

Answer (score 11):

The error is misleading as it's not about hydration but wrongly nested tags. I figured out the conflicting tags by removing HTML content and reloading the page until I found the problem (binary search).

In my case, it was caused by `<a>` within `<Link>`. I **thought** Next.js requires the `<a>` within the Link, but obviously that's not/no longer the case.

See the [Next.js documentation about `<Link>` tag](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link).

Comment: This can happen when you upgrade to Next.js 13.

Comment: I had a nested `<a>` within `<Link>` and am using Next 13. However, removing the nested `<a>` did not fix the problem for me. I still see the error, but only for a very small fraction of traffic (~2%).

Answer (score 7):

Removing the `<p>` tag solved my similar problem with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

Comment: It might not be stupid. In my case, I had a component which put its `children` inside an `Elem` which apparently was a `<p>`. Hydration failed when the `children` was dangerously set inner HTML . Got rid of the component, and it works fine now. (I could have changed the component config to use a different element. But I realized I didn't need the component.)

Answer (score 5):

I have React 18.2.0 with Next.js 12.2.4, and I fix hydration with this code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Breakpoint, BreakpointProvider } from 'react-socks';
import '../styles/globals.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true)
  }, [])

  if (!showChild) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <BreakpointProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </BreakpointProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Since useEffect only runs in the client, this code effectively prevents server-side rendering from happening at all. That may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Just go to the browser, Chrome → three bars button on top right corner (hamburger menu) → more tools → clear browsing history → delete cookies.

No more error.

Comment: This does actually work. Sometimes it seems the errors are not actually valid. For me I cleared the local storage on the localhost application I was developing and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

**Disabling SSR on specific components**

Doing `ssr:false` on importing component as dynamic worked for me. For more details, go to the Next.js official website [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const NoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/no-ssr'), { ssr: false })

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NoSSR />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use HTML tags you want to place them in the correct way and correct order. In Next.js.

Example: If you use *[table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)*.

->  You must add the *[tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)* tag

```html
<!-- Wrong -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Element</td>
    <td>Element</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Correct Way -->

<table>
  <tbody> <!-- This is a Must -->
    <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran this piece of code and the problem went away:

```js
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true);
  }, []);
  if (!showChild) {
    return null;
  }
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return <></>;
  } else {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel)'s [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error), this can be caused by

1. Incorrect nesting of HTML tags

   1. `<p> nested in another <p> tag`
   2. `<div> nested in a <p> tag`
2. Using checks like typeof window !== 'undefined' in your rendering logic
3. Using browser-only APIs like window or localStorage in your rendering logic
4. [Browser extensions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24430) modifying the HTML
5. Incorrectly configured [CSS-in-JS libraries](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js)
6. Incorrectly configured [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge)/CDN that attempts to modify the HTML response, such as Cloudflare Auto Minify

### Solution 1: Using useEffect to run on the client only

Ensure that the component renders the same content server-side as it does during the initial client-side render to prevent a hydration mismatch. You can intentionally render different content on the client with the useEffect hook.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])

  // return <h1>{isClient ? 'This is never prerendered' : 'Prerendered'}</h1>
  return <div> {isClient && (<ClientComponent/>)} </div>

}
```

During React hydration, useEffect is called. This means browser APIs like window are available to use without hydration mismatches.

### Solution 2: Disabling SSR on specific components

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const NoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/no-ssr'), { ssr: false })

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NoSSR />
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Solution 3: Using suppressHydrationWarning

Sometimes content will inevitably differ between the server and client, such as a timestamp. You can silence the hydration mismatch warning by adding `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` to the element.

```
<time datetime="2016-10-25" suppressHydrationWarning />
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work:

```
 function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        setShowing(true);
      }, []);

      if (!showing) {
        return null;
      }

      if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return <></>;
      } else {
        return (
           <RecoilRoot>
             <MainLayout>
                 <Component {...pageProps} />
              </MainLayout>
           </RecoilRoot>
        );
      }
    }

 export default MyApp;
```

Here I used [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) for state management.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Next.js and [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) with [Emotion](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) as the styling engine, then you may need to check the semantics of your components. You can find hints in the errors logged to the browser console.

Example: adding `Box` component inside `Iconbutton` will cause an error

There isn't any need to create a custom Next.js `_document.js` file, because *@emotion/react* version 10 and above works with Next.js by default.

Answer (score 2):

#### Make sure to wrap the lazy modules you import in `Suspense`

In my case I imported:

```js
const Footer = React.lazy(() => import('../Footer/Index'));
```

But I was using it just like a normal module.

```js
<Footer />
```

I wrapped it in `Suspense` and the error was gone.

```js
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
  <Footer />
</Suspense>
```

---

#### Bottom line

If this error is given to you on the home page, try to comment some of the components you use until you find where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes in Next.js, because dangerouslySetInnerHTML support only the [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) tag. If you insert with another tag, it does not work.

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:data.description}}></div>
```

Comment: I have used dangerouslySetInnerHTML in all kinds of tags without any issue, do you have any documentation of your statement ?

Comment: A citation would be helpful...

Answer (score 2):

In Next.js v13 and later, you shouldn't use `<a>` as the child inside `<Link>`.
If you use that, you'll get an error.

In this case, I use that in another way:

```
const Child = () => <a>hello my friend</a>

const Parent = () => {
 return (
  <Link href="/">
    <Child />
  </Link>
 )
}
```

Here I got this error, and I changed the child structure for removing `<a>` to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that initially rendered UI changes after the initial render based on layout size / parent item size detections.

I was rendering a component which requires to use window size. For the initial render my `useBreakpoint` hook returns null since the `window` object is **undefined**.

You can utilize [useLayoutEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect) to wait for to able to access properties of layout before the initial render.

```
  const currentBreakpoint = useBreakpoint();

  const [isLayoutReady, setIsLayoutReady] = React.useState(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setIsLayoutReady(true);
  }, []);

  const itemToShow =
    currentBreakpoint === Breakpoint.xl ? props.item : null;

  return (
   <div>
     {isLayoutReady && itemToShow}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine is a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) application.

I am using the `react-use-cart` module and it seems it has issues with `react @18.0.0`.

I am not sure how this is possible but downgrading to `react @17.0.2` removed my errors.

Previously I was using `react @18.0.0`.

I simply ran `npm uninstall react react-dom` and installed versions `@17.0.2`.

Wahala, everything now works as expected.

Comment: Hey! no need to downgrade, just reformat the object used from the react-use-cart. To clarify more, the items object should bect Json stringified then json parsed inside another variable and that variable insteead, :      /// const { items } = useCart()
    const [allItems, setallItems] = useState([{}])
    useEffect(() => {
        setallItems(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items)))
    }, [items])   ///    And the same goes for the cartTotal number just set it in a useState const and it shall work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when tried to put a div inside Card Text of React-Bootstrap.

The error can be reproduced by:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
...
const testPage : NextPage = () => {
...
return (
...
<Card.Text>
    <div>It's an error</div>
</Card.Text>
...
)}

export default testPage
```

To fix it, I just removed the HTML tag.

I think that some React components don't accept HTML tags inside.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's a user error in a nested list. I forgot adding a `ul` in [`li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), so it was just nested `li`s.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don’t have `next/Link` nested. I needed to refactor the code and forgot that I had a `next/Link` before wrapping the image.

For example

```html
<CompanyCardStyle className={className}>
    <!-- Open Link -->
    <Link href={route('companyDetail', { slug: company.slug })}>
        <a className='d-flex align-items-center'>
            <div className='company-card'>
                <div className='d-flex align-items-center col-name-logo'>
                    <div className='company-logo'>
                        <!-- Remove link and let the <a> child -->
                        <Link href={route('companyDetail', { slug: company.slug })}>
                            <a><img src={company.logoUrl} width={'100%'} /></a>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <h6 className='mb-0'>{company.name}</h6>
                </div>
                .....
            </div>
        </a>
    </Link>
</CompanyCardStyle>
```

Comment: I had a <Link/> nested inside a <Link/> in my remix app. Removing the inner <Link/> removed the browser warning.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I moved the pages directory in Next.js. I solved it by deleting the *.next* folder and rebuilding it using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) build.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by Next.js **dynamic** import with **ssr: false**:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { Suspense } from 'react'

const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
    ssr: false,
})

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <DynamicHeader />
    )
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution obviously.

Answer (score 1):

My case was that I used the [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) without [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) in [`thead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) in Next.js.

It was:

```html
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <th>head</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I added `tr` inside `thead`:

```html
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This is surely a problem related to tags. If you are using Next.js as a front end framework, I'd suggest to use 'Box' tag for the component where you are using your child components. It will allow you to use most of the tags successfully inside your child component. For having extra safe, you can use template literals to wrap the child component.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to using server-client-based conditional renders.

I.e., if you use a block based on the existence of window (i.e., when React hydrates and we're on client side), but it differs in SSR'ed condition, hydration fails as initial UI mismatches server side render (SSR).

```
typeof window !== 'undefined' ? <div>something</div> : <div> something else</div>
```

With the above code, you're mismatching server side render with client render, avoid these clauses and use a different approach to your logic to fix this error, i.e., use useState hook to keep this logic outside the function by setting it initially at componentDidMount stage using useEffect hook with an empty array as second attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me when I tried to render my component as client-side rendering, and it mismatched with hydration. So we can disable hydration during client-side rendering to fix this problem.

The given method below worked for me:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

function Mycomponent(){
   return (
     <h1>Hello world<h1/>
  )
}

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Mycomponent), { ssr: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

As the solutions in previous answers, it is correct that the error itself was not so explanatory, and yes the issue was the tags being misplaced issue.

In my case, I am using Next.js 13.4, and I was trying to show a Navbar component that was separately created, so I wanted to add it to my root Layout. I was applying the Navbar wrong.

**Wrong**

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={d_script.className}>
      <Navbar />
      <body> {children} </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**Correct**

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={d_script.className}>
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

As Navabar is shown within the body, so it should be wrapped within it, and it is also a tag issue so the error 'Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server' was shown.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an error while hydrating the React component tree because I imported a package incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was having an empty `div` inside another `div`. I was using Next.js 13 and was giving me the above error. Then when I was investigating, I noticed that having an empty `div` causes Next.js problems.

Bad:

```html
<div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Good:

```html
<div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
   <div><label>some content</label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Next.js and Faker.js, and I just use conditional rendering and it's solved. I think it happened because the values from Faker.js changes twice when page first loading.

The code below may help you.

```
    export default function Story() {
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    setAvatar(faker.image.avatar());
    setName(faker.name.findName());
    }, []);

    return (
    <>
      {avatar && name && (
      <div>
        <Image
          src={avatar}
          alt="Story Profile Picture"
          width={50}
          height={50}
      />
        <p>{name}</p>
      </div>
      )}
    </>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* wrap your component that causes this error with Nossr from MUI (Material UI):

```
import NoSsr from "@mui/material/NoSsr";

<NoSsr> {your contents} </NoSsr>
```

To get more information: *[No SSR](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-no-ssr/)*

Comment: This is the same as other solutions on this page, it is not tackling the underlying issue, this will only render client side

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I used reverse() function before mapping my list, I was getting a similar error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the solution then?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither making the HTML more semantic nor modifying the `_app.tsx` to check if the `window` was loaded.

The only solution, for now, was to downgrade the React version and the React DOM.

I'm using Next.js.

I switched to version 17.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this problem because I had used `<img />` tag instead of Next.js `<Image />` tag because I couldn't use tailwind classes with the `<Image />` tag. Replacing the `<img />` tag with Next.js `<Image />` tag solved the issue for me. Then I wrapped the `<Image />` tag with a `div` tag and added the classes to that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue using Next.js with [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/).
The actual solution is to use Next.js dynamic import.
In the example below, do not import header component as:

```
import Header from "../components/header"
```

Instead do:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
  suspense: true,
})
```

Check the Next.js documentation: *[Lazy Loading](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)*

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue even with `create-next-app` without any changes and tried with a different browsers and profiles. I see that there is no problem with them so I investigated my extensions but it didn't solve the problem.

Finally, I've solved it by investigating Google Chrome [Web development tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) settings. My problem is related to "Enable Local Overrides". So I unchecked that and it was solved.

Enable Local Overrides on Chrome Settings

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying the Next.js application to [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) using [PM2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PM2_(software)), you just have to rebuild and restart your application process.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was I forgot to wrap the `<td>` element inside a `<tr>` element.

It gives you an error.

```html
<thead className="w-full">
    <td className="w-1/12"></td>
    <td className="w-8/12"></td>
    <td></td>
</thead>
```

The correct way:

```html
<thead className="w-full">
    <tr>
        <td className="w-1/12"></td>
        <td className="w-8/12"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was caused by the **date-fns** package. After removing the component that was using the date formatting, the error message which was showing up only after deploying went away.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error in Next.js when trying to work using context and localstorage. The problem was solved by doing a check in _app.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33180453)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you're using a state management like [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)), better to have a Boolean state like 'isHydrated' with an initial value of 'false'. Once the initial UI is initialized, set it to 'true'. Consume this value in every component with dynamic UI rendering that will possibly encounter with this error.

*Do not* put this state at the component level. This will affect initial rendering as the component will recreate 'isHydrated' with an initial value of 'false':

```
function App() {
  const [isHydrated, setIsHydrated] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsHydrated(true)
  }, []);

  return (
  <div>
    {isHydrated ? <p>Hello</p> : null}
  </div>
  )
}

function Component() {
  const [isHydrated, setIsHydrated] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsHydrated(true)
  }, []);

  return (
  <div>
    {isHydrated ? <p>Hello</p> : null}
  </div>
  )
}
```

*Instead*, do something like this:

```
// Initialize UI rendering

function App() {
  const isHydrated = useSelector(s => s.isHydrated)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_IS_HYDRATED' })
  }, []);

  return (
  <div>
    {isHydrated ? <p>Hello</p> : null}
  </div>
  )
}

// Just consume the state at the component level and will render correctly when
// navigating to other page with 'isHydrated' value of 'true'

function Component() {
  const isHydrated = useSelector(s => s.isHydrated)

  return (
  <div>
    {isHydrated ? <p>Hello</p> : null}
  </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed `<body> <body/>` in the body from *App.js*.

```html
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  head() {
    return (
      <div>
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <title>React App</title>
        </head>
      </div>
    );
  }

  body() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Client says Hello World</h1>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.head()}
        {this.body()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I got success after removing `<body> <body/>`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

One more tiny finding from Next.js + [Chakra UI](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui), please also ensure `NEVER` do something like below:

```html
<a href="https://github.com/xxx" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  <IconButton
    as="a"
    href="#"
    aria-label="GitHub"
    icon={<FaGithub fontSize="1.25rem" />}
  />
</a>
```

This will also trigger the above error:

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Conclusion: please ensure the code you write is valid and make sense during debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got a similar error and I realized that it happens when a component has a nested Next.js Link (next/link):

```
<Link>
...
 <NestedComponenWithAnotherLink />
...
</Link>
```

=> Next.js 13.1.6

Answer (score 0):

This error means that in the HTML DOM tree there are some semantic issues.

For example: `<tbody>` has direct children `<div>` instead of
`<tr>`.

So, improving those issues, we can get right basis for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Next.js 13.

I had this issue when I forgot to utilize `next/script` instead of the HTML `script` element. This was in the `layout.tsx` file where I wanted to apply the script on all pages.

In my case, the script was rendering an element, and when routing state changes, this element is not rendered, thus the script wasn't loading and causing the hydration error.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 
export default function App() {
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])
 
  return isClient ? (<div>Content</div>) : <></>
}
```

Source: *[Text content does not match server-rendered HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)*

Comment: There isn't ***any*** original contribution here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Chakra UI](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui) with Next.js, when I removed `Heading` tag and `Link` tag my error is gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend inspecting the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and looking for inconsistencies, and using an HTML linter. There are a number of causes too numerous to list, but you inspecting the DOM will allow you to find instances of other answers that may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue, because I had used

```
<Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1, py: 1, mr: 10, ml: 10 }}>
      <div>
          ...
      </div>
</Typography>
```

above structure in my code. I think *Typography* is acting as a normal HTML `<p>` element. And Next.js [mentions](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) about this issue:

Incorrect nesting of HTML tags

- `<p>` nested in another `<p>` tag
- `<div>` nested in a `<p>` tag
- [Interactive Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactive-content-2) cannot be nested (`<a>` nested in a `<a>` tag,  nested in
  a `<button>` tag, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem due to nonuse of the `useEffect` hook while calling the fetch API in Next.js 14. My API is fetching JSON again and again, hence Next.js gives me an error of hydration. So add an API call within the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I use `"react-player": "^2.13.0"` in `"next": "14.0.4"`,
`"react": "^18"`. I got this error

```
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

I used this way to fix that

```
"use client"
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const MyVideoPlayer = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyVideoPlayer'), { ssr: false })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <MyVideoPlayer/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in an edge case that I encountered - if you use an extension that modifies your page in some way such as Dark Reader, this can cause the hydration error message to pop up even if your code is good.  Just disable the extension in this case to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in Next `12.3.1`. As many have answered the issue looked related to invalid DOM nesting. This error message is not very descriptive in the build. So I ran the project locally `npm run dev` and navigated to the the page where this error was showing on the console. In the development run I could see the exact DOM Nesting error in the console like:

`next-dev.js:28 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>. Add a <tbody>, <thead> or <tfoot> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.`

Thereby I fixed my invalid DOM nesting error as the error was descriptive as above. You can try the same without trying to manually figure out which are the erroneous elements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening because of the cache. Running `npm cache clean --force` and cleaning the browser cache, as well as rerunning `npm run dev` fixed it for me.

Edit:
Apparently it happened because of the local storage; before rendering, the server had no access to the local storage; hence, it's rendering different content compared to the browser. Deleting my cache worked because I deleted the local storage, so of course the error source is gone. Updating the code on how to load the local storage fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me in Next.js and I found out I accidentally moved the *index.js* file into another folder. So I returned it to the pages folder and all was well.

Answer (score -1):

I just faced the similar error. In my case I was also using Nextjs, basically the problem was that I was not using the <tbody> tag inside the <table> tag. And usually, browsers automatically adds the <tbody> if I just place <tr> inside the <table> tag, and don't specify the either *tbody* or *thead* tag inside the table tag.

I believe this can apply to all other similar HTML tags and it was telling in the error, that something is rendering on the DOM which you've not mentioned in code.

One more thing. I was using the nested loop in that particular section first to map the table rows and then a certain table data field. When I removed the nested map it worked without adding the *tbody* and also worked when I added the *tbody*, but kept the nested loop. So, I'm not sure why it's weird. However, it's working, so f* it.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me to get client side rendering throughout the app. No more worries about using `window` throughout the rest of the app.

```js
import useSSR from 'use-ssr'

function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta name='description' content='Generated by create next app' />
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>
      <ClientSideRenderedNextJS>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ClientSideRenderedNextJS>
    </>
  )
}

function ClientSideRenderedNextJS({ children }) {
  const [domLoaded, setDomLoaded] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setDomLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  const { isServer } = useSSR()
  if (!domLoaded) return null
  if (isServer) return <></>

  return children
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true);
  }, []);

  if (!showChild) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return <></>;
  }
  else {
    return (
      <Provider client={state}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I had similar issues. Reverting back to a stable version of React worked the magic.

Consider reverting back to React 17.

Here is [a GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35773).