# Can I pass data fetched in getStaticProps to a component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My getstaticProps:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  const mainMenuData = await fetch(
    `https://example.com/get/main-menu`
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    props: {
      mainMenuData,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

Using the component:

```
<Header data={mainMenuData} />
```

My component:

```
export default function Header({ data }) {

  return (
    <>

      {data.main_menu}

    </>
  );
}
```

The data is an object, and I can access it so technically I know it's possible. However when I start mapping through the data I keep getting the error:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server
```

I'm new to Next and I'm not sure this method is correct.

Edit: Page component

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Header from "../components/header";

export default function Page({ mainMenuData }) {

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
      <Header data={mainMenuData} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  const mainMenuData = await fetch(
    `https://example.com/get/main-menu`
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    props: {
      mainMenuData,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

Comment: Please show the page component where you are using your `Header`.

Comment: I think the error is due to not wrapping the data you are passing to `Header` in a jsx element. Try using a jsx element inside of `Header` like a `div` or `ul` if it's a list for example and let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: @ivanatias this doesn't solve it

Comment: I see. You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706064/react-18-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-render) thread, this is a very common issue in Nextjs, maybe it can help you.

Comment: @ivanatias you were correct the first time, I had some nested maps and I didn't wrap them correctly, it got confusing, Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the issue. Should I put the comment as an answer so you can close this question?

Comment: Yes please do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error might be happening due to not wrapping the data you are passing to `Header` properly in a JSX element. Try using a JSX element inside of `Header` like a `div` or `ul` if it's a list for example.

Also, avoid some JSX wrapping patterns such as, for example, a `p` tag wrapping up a `div`, `section`, etc. Next.js will most likely throw a similar error because of this.

[Reference thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706064/react-18-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-render)