# Next.js Hydration Error with Shadcn Dialog Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, hydration

I'm encountering a hydration error in a Next.js project when using the Shadcn Dialog component. The error message is:

"Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Here are the key components:

**modal.tsx:**

```
// Importing Dialog components from Shadcn
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogDescription, DialogHeader, DialogTitle } from "@/components/ui/dialog";

interface ModalProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({
  title,
  description,
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  children
}) => {
  const onChange = (open: boolean) => {
    if (!open) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return ( 
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onChange}>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            {description}
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};


import { Modal } from "@/components/ui/modal";

const SetupPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-4" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
      <Modal title="Test" description="Test Desc" isOpen onClose={() => {}}>
        Children
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SetupPage;
```

I've included the relevant code snippets, and the issue arises during hydration. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Attempted to use Shadcn's Dialog component in a Next.js project. Expected smooth rendering, but encountered a hydration error:

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error as you did. Hydration error often occurs when you are dealing with modal pop-ups, caused by the mismatching of the rendering result between the server side and the client side.

One workaround is to add a checking logic to ensure your Dialog is only rendered on the client side:

```js
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return <YourDialogComponent/>  // only on client side
```

I believe you are trying to build an e-commerce website watching [Code With Antonio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5miHyP6lExg) since your source code exactly matched the content of his tutorial (and I am doing the same thing haha) (forgive me if I am wrong).
And he did the same thing as described above in his tutorial afterwards so you won't get this error after a while if you keep following.

Cheers!

See also:

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

https://github.com/radix-ui/primitives/issues/1386

[How to solve react hydration error in Nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162551/how-to-solve-react-hydration-error-in-nextjs)

Answer (score 1):

Ive been using dynamic imports with ssr set to false as a workaround for several shadcn components. I also think modals should be dynamic in general.
Eg:

```js
const Modal = dynamic(() => import("./pathToFile/Modal"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <AnyPlaceHolder />,
})
```

Comment: I think, this is a good practice until shadcn makes changes!

Answer (score 0):

Much better now.
Because : To dynamically import a named export, you can return it from the Promise returned by import()

```
const Modal = dynamic(
  () => import("../components/ui/modal").then((mod) => mod.Modal),
  {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  }
);
```