# Hydration Error in Next.JS with Trpc / React-Query (even when not displaying the pulled data)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, hydration, trpc.io

```js
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [filterPublishedPosts, setFilterPublishedPosts] = useState(false)

  const { data, isLoading } = trpc.item.getAllPosts.useQuery({
    text: "from tRPC", filters: {
      filterPublishedPosts: filterPublishedPosts
    }
  });

  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={() => {
            setFilterPublishedPosts(!filterPublishedPosts)
          }}>
            Show Only Published Posts
      </button>
      // .... at some point, display some data here
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I am using `useState` on the frontend to keep track of what the user wants to see and then pass that down as a variable to trpc / react-query.

Why does it give me an hydration error? Not sure I understand why the data would be different on the server / client in this case? But I get:

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the > server.
>
> See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Don't understand that though, because the hydration error comes up, even if I don't render any data! Just fetching it.

Comment: There should be more info the in the console.
It could be because of wrong HTML semantics https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870995/15814542.
Using the hook inside the page component

Comment: thanks a lot, I had something wrong with my HTML semantics!! If you want to submit this comment as an answer, I'd pick that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be more info in the console. It could be because of wrong HTML semantics. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870995/15814542).