# NextJS Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: next.js, solana, solana-web3js, react-18, hydration

I am implementing solana-wallet-adapter to my nextJS app. I got the following error when I run the app: "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

How to solve this?

no solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706064/react-18-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-render) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In [nextjs 13](https://nextjs.org/) and in [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router) root layout is a by default server component so we can not add a client component to server component
example you mark page as "use client"

app/page.js

```
"use client"

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>It produce Hydration Error </h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

so just add some extra code

```
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function Home() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Success code </h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply updated google chrome and my problem is solved.

**Update:** 
The same error and "Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML." came back the next day. I have no idea why. I will update here when I solve it.

**2nd Update:** 
The solution is [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/error-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-rendered) , already covered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some extensions in your browser that change the view, try disable it, it worked for me. in my case it was Dark Reader extension.