# Why using Math.random() in useState causes server rendering issues?

Tags: next.js

I faced a strange issue when I randomly try to set true or false in useState using `Math.random()`.

Example:

```
const [hasPrime] = useState(Math.random() < 0.5)

  ...

{hasPrime && (
    <div>
      <p>Free Next-day delivery</p>
    </div>
 )}
```

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

If I put in `useState` true or false, I will not get such error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706064/react-18-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-render)

Comment: My guess is that next wants a render to be deterministic. In other words, if you render the same thing twice it should have the same result.

Comment: @vighnesh153 no, it doesn't, my question is more about useState()

Comment: @Evert I am not sure, I found of use Math.random() in example on YouTube for NextJS 12 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server rendered HTML doesn't match the client rendered HTML, the React tree goes out of sync with the DOM. In NextJS, the component is rendered both on the client and on the server. While rendering on your server, `Math.random() < 0.5` would have been different from the value generated while rendering on the client which causes the conditional `div` to be added/removed from the HTML. hence throwing the error. Check out [React Hydration Error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)

When you use `true` or `false` in the `useState`, React will or will not render the conditional `div` but whatever it renders, it will be the same on both the client side and on the server side.